# Cypress tests for Monopoly

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am creating Monopoly using react hooks. I am using cypress for testing it. The first test I have to create is to check about dice rolls. I have three tests in which I am repeating the same kind of code. How can I refactor this?

```
//A funcction to get the rolls of dice in number
function getDiceRolls() {
   const dices = Cypress.$(".dice");
   return [dices[0].children.length, dices[1].children.length];
}

//Get the player who has the current turn
function getActiveTurn() {
   const playerTabHeads = Cypress.$(".player-tab-head");
   return playerTabHeads
      .toArray()
      .findIndex((head) => head.classList.contains("active"));
}

//Get the total number of players
function getNoOfPlayers() {
   return Cypress.$(".player-tab-head").toArray().length;
}

//Get the 'piece' element of the required player
function getPiece(id: number) {
   return Cypress.$(".piece.small.piece-" + id);
}

//Get the tile no in which a player is standing
function getTileNoOfPiece(id: number) {
   return +((getPiece(id).toArray()[0].parentNode!.parentNode as HTMLElement)
      .dataset.tileno as string);
}

//Get owner of specific tile
function getOwnerOfTile(tile: ITile) {
   const playerTabBodies = Cypress.$(".player-tab-body").toArray();
   return playerTabBodies.findIndex((playerTabBody) => {
      const propCards = Array.from(
         playerTabBody.querySelectorAll(".prop-card")
      );
      return propCards.some((propCard) => propCard.innerHTML === tile.name);
   });
}

//Get the money of specified player
function getMoneyOfPlayer(playerNo: number) {
   return Number(
      Cypress.$(".player-tab-head")
         .toArray()
         [playerNo].querySelector(".player-money")
         ?.innerHTML.replace("$", "")
   );
}

//Get all the 40 objects 
let allTiles: ITile[];
before(() => {
   cy.fixture("allTiles").then((data) => {
      allTiles = data;
   });
});


describe("Rolling System", function () {
   beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit("localhost:3000");
   });
   //TO CHECK BUTTON DISABLING
   it("disables button correctly", function () {
      //To keep track of roll button
      let isRollDisabled = false;

      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         cy.wait(100).then(() => {
            //End turn if roll button is disabled(means can't roll)
            if (isRollDisabled) {
               if (Cypress.$(".btn-buy-prop").length > 0) {
                  cy.get(".btn-buy-prop").click();
               }
               cy.wait(100).then((x) => {
                  cy.get(".btn-end-turn").click();
                  isRollDisabled = false;
               });
            }

            //Roll the die
            else {
               let roll1: number;
               let roll2: number;
               cy.get(".btn-roll")
                  .click()
                  .then(() => {
                     [roll1, roll2] = getDiceRolls();
                     //If doubles are not rolled disable roll btn
                     if (roll1 !== roll2) {
                        cy.get(".btn-roll").should("be.disabled");
                        isRollDisabled = true;
                     }
                     //Otherwise it should be disabled 
                     else {
                        cy.get(".btn-roll").should("not.be.disabled");
                     }
                  });
            }
         });
      }
   });

   //Check the movement
   it("Moves correctly", function () {
      let isRollDisabled = false;
      //To keep track of previous position of each piece
      let oldPositions: number[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         cy.wait(100).then(() => {
            let activeTurn: number;
            let totalRoll: number;

            //End turn
            if (isRollDisabled) {
               if (Cypress.$(".btn-buy-prop").length > 0) {
                  cy.get(".btn-buy-prop").click();
               }
               cy.get(".btn-end-turn").click();
               isRollDisabled = false;
            }

            //Roll die
            else {
               let roll1: number;
               let roll2: number;
               cy.get(".btn-roll")
                  .click()
                  .then((x) => {
                     //Get the total roll
                     [roll1, roll2] = getDiceRolls();
                     totalRoll = roll1 + roll2;

                     //Disable button if no doubles are rolled
                     if (roll1 !== roll2) {
                        cy.log("Roll is disabled");
                        isRollDisabled = true;
                     }
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                     //Fill old positions is empty fill it with 0's
                     if (oldPositions.length === 0) {
                        oldPositions = Array(getNoOfPlayers()).fill(0);
                     }

                     //Get current Tile no
                     activeTurn = getActiveTurn();
                     let tileNoOfActivePiece = getTileNoOfPiece(activeTurn);
                     
                     let newPosition = oldPositions[activeTurn] + totalRoll;
                     if (newPosition > 39) {
                        newPosition -= 40;
                     }
                     //Calculate the new expected position
                     oldPositions[activeTurn] = newPosition;
                     expect(tileNoOfActivePiece).to.be.equal(newPosition);
                  });
            }
         });
      }
   });

   //Test the result of landing on tile.

   it("Give tile landing response", function () {
      let isRollDisabled = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         cy.wait(100).then(() => {
            let activeTurn: number = getActiveTurn();
            let totalRoll: number;
            let money: number = getMoneyOfPlayer(activeTurn);

            //End turn
            if (isRollDisabled) {
               if (Cypress.$(".btn-buy-prop").length > 0) {
                  cy.get(".btn-buy-prop").click();
               }
               cy.get(".btn-end-turn").click();
               isRollDisabled = false;
            }

            //Roll die
            else {
               let roll1: number;
               let roll2: number;
               cy.get(".btn-roll")
                  .click()
                  .then((x) => {
                     //Get the total roll
                     [roll1, roll2] = getDiceRolls();
                     totalRoll = roll1 + roll2;

                     //Disable button if no doubles are rolled
                     if (roll1 !== roll2) {
                        cy.log("Roll is disabled");
                        isRollDisabled = true;
                     }
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                     //Fill old positions is empty fill it with 0's

                     //Get current Tile no
                     console.log(money.toString());
                     let tileNoOfActivePiece = getTileNoOfPiece(activeTurn);
                     let tile = allTiles[tileNoOfActivePiece];
                     let ownerOfTile = getOwnerOfTile(tile);
                     //Normal Properties
                     if (ownerOfTile === -1 && tile.price) {
                        //Shows the big prop card
                        cy.log("Shows the prop card");
                        cy.get(".big-prop-card")
                           .should("be.visible")
                           .should("contain", tile.name);

                        //Buying the property
                        cy.get(".btn-buy-prop")
                           .click()
                           .then(() => {
                              //Change the owner
                              const newOwnerOfTile = getOwnerOfTile(tile);
                              expect(newOwnerOfTile).to.be.eq(activeTurn);

                              //Decreases money
                              const newMoneyOfPlayer =
                                 money - (tile.price as number);
                              expect(newMoneyOfPlayer).to.be.eq(
                                 getMoneyOfPlayer(activeTurn)
                              );
                           });
                     }

                     //Income taxes
                     else if (tile.type === "income-tax") {
                        console.log(money);
                        cy.log(money.toString());
                        expect(money - (tile.taxValue as number)).to.be.eq(
                           getMoneyOfPlayer(activeTurn)
                        );
                     }
                  });
            }
         });
      }
   });
```

In the above code I have to use `isRollDisabled` in each even when it's not required in the test. Kindly tell me the way to refactor the code.